# No error thrown by compiler, if function declaration is not made for the function defined after main()

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 int ret;
 printf("\n main() is called! \n");
 ret = func(1,2);
 printf("\n The ret value is : %d \n",ret);
 return 0;
}
int func(int x,int y){
  printf("\n func() is called! x: %d , y : %d \n",x,y);
  if(x == 1){
    return y+x;
  }
  else{
    return y-x;
  }
}
```

This program doesnt have a function declaration in the main(). This program is not giving any compilation error. Why ?

Comment: Try compiling with -Werror

Comment: @pleas : I tried that also .. The result is the same

Comment: @oli : It gives a warning, implicit declaration of function declaration

Comment: to be considered `int func(int, int) ` implicitly.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : I agree with u. But it has to throw an error as it doesnt know abt func()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the return type of your function is `int`. When you have a function call that isn't declared yet, the return type defaults to `int` in C language. In your case, the call  `func(1,2);`, defaults to `int`, and the later defined function is also, `int`. That's why there is no conflict.

When you change the return type to anything other than `int`, you will get an error.

For example below code gives `conflicting-types` error, because. Function call implicitly declared an `int` returning function, and later the original function definition has the type `float`.

This code gives the error:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
 float ret;
 printf("\n main() is called! \n");
 ret = func(1,2);
 printf("\n The ret value is : %f \n",ret);
 return 0;
}
float func(int x,int y){
  printf("\n func() is called! x: %d , y : %d \n",x,y);
  if(x == 1){
    return x+y;
  }
  else{
    return y-x;
  }
}
```

**EDIT:**

In C language, In early phases of the compiler, first when function calls are seen they are implicitly declared and in the later phases searched for the definition. So, when search fails, it gives an undefined function error but not undeclared function. But when definition is there but types are conflicting conflicting types error is given...but in your case default declaration and original declaration is same that's why you didn't get any error.

You have to also note that, there is no need to immediately abort the compilation if function is defined as soon as it has not seen the declaration. First it just flags `implicit` declaration and if there is no definition at all no where in the code. Then it throws the `undefined function error`.

Comment: inside main, when compiler executes the function call "func(1)" , it has to throw an error, as it doesnt know where it is loacated and should also check for the no of parameters it takes.

Comment: @Angus in early phases of the compiler, first when calls are seen they are implicitly declared and in the later phases searched for the definition in C. So, when search fails, it gives an undefined function error but not undeclared function. But when definition is there but types are conflicting conflicting types error is given...but in your case default declaration and original declaration is same that's why you didn't get any error

Comment: if return type of the function is float, the error is : "func was not declared in this scope", for other types , it is : "conflicting types for a function"

Comment: Also , why is it not giving me an error , if i pass a single parameter though the function has to take 2 parameters ??

Comment: @Angus except for `int`, for all the other types including `float`, I'm getting `conflicting types for a function`... and I think you are talking about C. I hope, you get `func was not declared in this scope` comes in C++ I hope... did you accidentally saved your file as `.cpp` .

Comment: Sorry, I get conflicting types for a function , for all the data types other than int. My doubt is , why func(1) is not throwing error as it should accept 2 parameters. I tried func(1,2,3) too. its not throwing any errors

Comment: @Angus because a garbage values is passed to your second parameter implicitly....when compiled the compiler automatically did this

Comment: line by line execution happens. so how does the compiler know the function takes 2 parameters, as my function call is first executed with a single parameter

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31327/discussion-between-pinkpanther-and-angus)

Comment: @Angus yes, execution takes line by line. But not necessarily the compilation. There are lot more complex things happen in compilation of a program. you will know when you study compilers course

Comment: @Angus since, C is higher level than assembly we are able to call with number of parameters at a time. But actually when it got compiled to assembly...only `call function` happen, parameters are passed in many ways...through register through stack.... it varies across compilers...so unfed parameters taking the values from the area of it doesn't have actual right...hence the garbage....it's very difficult to discuss all about that in comments

Answer (score 3):

In the old days of C, that was somewhat usual, it is called *implicit declaration*. The idea is that the compiler automatically generates a prototype for your function on first use, using the types of the parameters you happen to be using, and returning `int`.

Yes it is as bad an idea as it sounds... that's why modern compilers will issue a warning for this code. If you use `gcc` try compiling with `-Wall` to see the usual warnings.

PS: That's one of the reasons why `NULL` is defined as `((void*)0)` instead of simply `0`, so that automatic prototyping of functions such as `foo(NULL)` will get a `int foo(void*)` instead of `int foo(int)`.

Comment: Even if i call the function with a single parameter, it doesnt throw me an error

Comment: It's a little more complicated than that; the arguments first undergo *default argument promotions*.  (See C99, 6.5.2.2 p6).

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: You are right, of course. Actually it is more as if the prototype where `int func(...)`.

Comment: @Angus: Ah, but that's because when the compiler sees the real functions it notices that the previous prototype was implicit and issues the real one. This is by design.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler doesn't throw any error.. it just gives a warning

```
implicit declaration of function
```

if you compile the code with `-Wall` in `gcc`